# Как прочитать входящие письма и получить их вложения?

Tags: python, email

Нужно получить письмо со стороннего почтового сервиса (затем удалить его) и скачать прикреплённый к нему файл.

Comment: Ваш вопрос довольно общий - с чем конкретно возникают проблемы? С протоколом [IMAP](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/imaplib.html), с использованием библиотеки [email](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email-examples.html), проблемы с конкретным почтовым сервером?

Comment: Нужен пример кода, который скачивает все письма с потового ящика и сохраняет каждое в отдельный файл.

Comment: почтовый ящик - понятие расплывчатое. Многие так вообще скажут, что это железный ящик с прорезью. Почта на каком-то стороннем сервисе (mail.ru, gmail, yandex и т.д.) (или своем сервере), поддерживающем IMAP? Отмечу сразу, что это будет скорее всего невозможно, если на ящике прикручена двухфакторная авторизация.

Comment: Почтовый ящик на yandex без двухуровневой авторизации

Answer (score 6):

Рассмотрим на примере почтового сервиса от Yandex. Первое, что нам потребуется - адрес и порт IMAP сервера: https://yandex.ru/support/mail-new/mail-clients.html Такие же страницы есть и для любых других сервисов. Также по умолчанию доступ по IMAP выключен (из соображений безопасности) и вы, или администратор домена, должны его включить.

Второе, что вам может понадобиться - это описание протокола IMAP. Мне понравилась [вот такая картинка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32758506/1185696).

Третье - это непосредственно сам код. [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) запросит письмо, [email](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) его разберет на части. Как пример рассмотрим получение всех писем из "Входящие" от отправителя Yoba. Список "папок" можно получить методом [list()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.list).

```
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL

YA_HOST = "imap.yandex.ru"
YA_PORT = 993
YA_USER = "LOGIN"
YA_PASSWORD = "PASSWROD"
SENDER = "Yoba"

connection = IMAP4_SSL(host=YA_HOST, port=YA_PORT)
connection.login(user=YA_USER, password=YA_PASSWORD)
status, msgs = connection.select('INBOX')
assert status == 'OK'

typ, data = connection.search(None, 'FROM', '"%s"' %s SENDER)
print(data)
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, message_data= connection.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print(data)
    print('Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, message_data[0][1]))
connection.close()
connection.logout()
```

Самая первая `data` - это номера (в виде строки) писем из папки входящие, с указанным отправителем. Как-то так:

```
>>> [b'1757 1758 1759 1760 1774 1775']
```

message_data - части письма. У вас есть возможность запросить одно и то же в самых разных форматах - я выбрал формат RFC822 - это письмо целиком и его понимает модуль email. Вы можете запросить тело, [заголовки](https://pymotw.com/2/imaplib/#fetching-messages), вложения.

Затем необходимо извлечь вложения:

```
mail = email.message_from_bytes(message_data[0][1])

if mail.is_multipart():
    for part in mail.walk():
        content_type = part.get_content_type()
        filename = part.get_filename()
        if filename:
            # Нам плохого не надо, в письме может быть всякое барахло
            with open(part.get_filename(), 'wb') as new_file:
                new_file.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
```